# DNN menu change has caused an XSLT error

Tags: xslt, authentication, dotnetnuke, host

I am new to DNN and made some changes to the menu structure of a web site that was already set up.

Ultimately, I wanted to change the name of the 'Home' page to 'Shop Home' and found that simply changing the name had no effect.

I decided, instead, to create a new page and link it to the existing 'Home' page.

Now, when I hit 'Shop Home', I get the following error:

ErrorThe XSLT-Code cannot be blank. Please check your configuration in the backend system.

In addition, I can now no longer log on as host (or anyone else for that matter) so I can't access the admin functionality to return things to their previous state.

I'd love to hear from anyone about how to sort this out!?

Comment: What Menu are you using in your DNN site?

Comment: We found out what the problem was. So - to assist with anyone else who gets this error - here goes!

Comment: Basically, I am based in NZ and was adding any captions to the categories with NZ English as the language. The site is running on US English and so there was no translation for that particular language. As soon as the caption was defined using US English as well, the menu translated just fine. I hope this helps others and - Chris, thank you for making an effort to assist!